# struct int data type not working with relational operaters

Tags: c++, struct, void

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;
    struct studentInfo {
        string studentFname, studentLname;
        int testScore;
        char grade;
    }student[20];
    
    void inputs(studentInfo(&student)[20]) {
        ifstream openFile;
        openFile.open("Students.txt"); 
        if (!openFile.is_open()) 
            cerr << "ERROR! failed to open file\n";
    
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            openFile >> student[i].studentFname;
            openFile >> student[i].studentLname;
            openFile >> student[i].testScore;
        }
        openFile.close();
    }
    void grade(studentInfo(&student)[20]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            if (student[i].testScore >= 90)
                student[i].grade = 'A';
            if (student[i].testScore >= 80 && student[i].testScore < 90)
                student[i].grade = 'B';
            if (student[i].testScore >= 70 && student[i].testScore < 80)
                student[i].grade = 'C';
            if (student[i].testScore >= 60 && student[i].testScore < 70)
                student[i].grade = 'D';
            else
                student[i].grade = 'F';
        }
    }
    void best(studentInfo(&student)[20], int index) {
        int largest;
        largest = 0;
        for (int n = 0; n < 20; n++) {
            if (largest < student[n].testScore) {
                largest = student[n].testScore;
                index = n;
            }
        }
    
    }
    void output(studentInfo(&student)[20], int n) {
        ofstream outfile;
        outfile.open("StudentGrade.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            outfile << student[i].studentLname << ", " << student[i].studentFname << " " << student[i].testScore << " " << student[i].grade << endl;
        outfile << student[n].studentFname << " " << student[n].studentLname << " has the best grade!";
        outfile.close();
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        studentInfo Istudent[20];
        int tests[20];
        int large = 0;
            inputs(Istudent);
            for (int i = 0; i< 20; i++)
            Istudent[i].testScore= tests[i];
            grade(Istudent);
            best(Istudent, large);
            output(Istudent, large);
            return 0;
    }

Duckey Donald 85
Goof Goofy 89
Brave Balto 93
Snow Smitn 93
Alice Wonderful 89
Samina Akthar 85
Simba Green 95
Donald Egger 90
Brown Deer 86
Johny Jackson 95
Greg Gupta 75
Samuel Happy 80
Danny Arora 80
Sleepy June 70
Amy Cheng 83
Shelly Malik 95
Chelsea Tomek 95
Angela Clodfelter 95
Allison Nields 95
Lance Norman 88
```

My void functions best and grade don't seem to be working. When the program runs the grade function makes all the grades 'F' and the best function always picks the first name for the highest score. I've tried to sets the test scores in a different array but that didn't seem to help. Any help would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: `best` should take `index` as `int&`, otherwise `large` in `main` is not modified.

Comment: Thanks! that solves one of my problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `student[i]` is `87`, it will fulfill the second conditional and get a grade of `'B'`, but then it will also fail the fourth conditional and go into `else`, getting a grade of `'F'` which overwrites the `'B'`.

Only your fourth `if` is associated with the `else`. The above three are independent so the checks will occur unnecessarily.

```
                if (student[i].testScore >= 90)
                    student[i].grade = 'A';
                if (student[i].testScore >= 80 && student[i].testScore < 90)
                    student[i].grade = 'B';
                if (student[i].testScore >= 70 && student[i].testScore < 80)
                    student[i].grade = 'C';
                if (student[i].testScore >= 60 && student[i].testScore < 70)
                    student[i].grade = 'D';
                else
                    student[i].grade = 'F';
```

You should use an if-else

```
                if (student[i].testScore >= 90)
                    student[i].grade = 'A';
                else if (student[i].testScore >= 80)
                    student[i].grade = 'B';
                else if (student[i].testScore >= 70)
                    student[i].grade = 'C';
                else if (student[i].testScore >= 60)
                    student[i].grade = 'D';
                else
                    student[i].grade = 'F';
```

If the first conditional isn't fulfilled, you don't need to check it again in the second conditional. And the final `else` is associated with all the previous conditionals so if any of the above conditionals are true, the `else` won't be executed.